# Centos 7 SELinux Policy with Samba

Tags: nginx, centos, samba, selinux

My server under Centos 7 has Samba and Nginx services installed on

- To allow web application located in /www served by Nginx I use command

> ```
> chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /www
> ```

but in this case it's impossible to have permissions for shared /www directory by Samba.

- To allow access to Samba's shared directory /www I use command

> ```
>  chcon -R -t samba_share_t /www
> ```

at this time Nginx service has no access to files located in /www

I need access to /www files to develop web application and run it by Nginx instantly. I have no idea how to make it working same time having full access by Samba and Nginx. Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in this case Nginx service won't be able to access files under /www cause you have changed the file context
Try to label the /www recursively as : chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /www

then make a soft link to /www

> #### '# ln -s /www /mysambashare
>
> Using semanage does not relabel the link itself; just the target:
>
> #### '# semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t /mysambashare

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and was able to fix it by allowing Samba to access any content type. As the root user run one of the following commands...

Read-only access:

```
setsebool -P samba_export_all_ro on
```

Read-write access:

```
setsebool -P samba_export_all_rw on
```

Restart your Samba services afterwards and you should hopefully find that you have access to /var/www via Samba.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem,
temporary solution:

`semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_rw_t "/var/www(/.*)?"`

or:

`chcon -R -t public_content_rw_t /var/www`

This rule make folder www public for all apps.